# sending email test with postfix

Tags: postfix, mail, sendmail

I have installed `postfix` and I want to test the service to send mail. But the command line `mail` seems not to be recognized. I read that I should have installed `mailutils` and that I don't have all the required packages. So what I am suppose to install as packages to get the right functionality and to test the email sending ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [swaks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/swaks.1.html) for testing email sending. To install:

```
sudo apt install swaks
```

You can just run `swaks` command and input the fields when prompted or pass the arguments in CLI mode, for example:

```
swaks --to user@example.com --server test-server.example.net
```

Comment: thank you, I installed a wiki. But the inscription email confirmation are not sent. Am I supposed to install specific packages or configure postfix in a specific way ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. What "wiki"? What is an "inscription email"? What "specific packages" are you asking about? You already said you configured postfix in your question, right?

Comment: sorry if I am not clear. I meant a media-wiki which enable user to create an account. The system throws to the signing user a confirmation email and I don't know if I am supposed to add some specific packages

Comment: There's nothing about media-wiki in your original question. Please ask a new one describing precisely your goal, steps taken and your problem.